# How to use sum(x:y) when x and y are coming from other cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Headline basically states it:

Imagine A1=15, and A2=30

What I want is sum(B15:B30) where 15 and 30 are coming from the other two cells (or another formular for that matter).

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,A1):INDEX(B:B,A2))
```

[image]